# append parent div from within child divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a div before div 1, but the script will nestled in a few divs deep in the code. Would this work in theory?

```
<div id="1">
   <div id="2">
       <div id="3">
           <style>
           #4 {...}
           </style>
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
           <script>     
               $( "#4" ).before( $( "#1" ) );
           </script>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: don't start an element `ID` with a number > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I did that purely to simplify the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should inject a div element before the div with id 1.

```js
<div id="1">
   <div id="2">
       <div id="3">
           <style>
           </style>
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
           <script>
             var $div = $('<div></div>').attr('id', '4'); 

             $div.insertBefore('#1');
           </script>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, in your example above, can <div></div> be substituted with '#4' like my example above? thanks

Comment: one follow up.. i have created this new Div 4 and its in the right place in the code.. how do I fill this new div with html?

Comment: $div.html('some html'); will do

Comment: this would go after $div.insertBefore('#1'); ?

Comment: Either will work, as long as it is after the var $div is declared